# How to get songs I played in a day from Spotify API

Tags: python, api

I want to use Spotify API on Python (spotipy library) to retrieve all the songs I played in a day for analysis, everyday. I have only seen examples of people getting songs by playlist, etc, but haven't been able to see any example of getting all tracks played within a timeframe. Additionally, I also want to learn what are some tools I can use to automate this process of collecting the results at the end of each day and storing them in a database (and running the model, etc). Any help or reference is appreciated!

Comment: [`current_user_recently_played()`](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.19.0/#spotipy.client.Spotify.current_user_recently_played)

Comment: Assuming you have the proper Authorization built into your script, you create your spotipy client object sp = spotipy.Spotify() with the appropriate credentials, and then use sp.current_user_recently_played() to create the object. It takes parameters to set the scope of your query as well.